# trying to update values on datagridview in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm trying to allow values to be changed within the datagridview table

OnCellendEdit event

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conString))
{                    
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
    {
        conn.Open();

        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE employee SET @selected = '@upd' WHERE id = @id";                        

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@selected", dataGridView1.CurrentCell.OwningColumn.HeaderText);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@upd", dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
    }
}
this.employeeTableAdapter.Fill(this.testDataSet.employee);
```

Using the above to build the update query but it just resets upon pressing enter

```
@selected retrieves column name
@upd retrieves entered value
@id retrieves id number
```

So the final query should be

```
UPDATE employees  
SET firstName = 'john' 
WHERE id = 1
```

but upon execution no changes are committed and the value resets to original.

Looked at values and they are being retrieved correctly.

Comment: your code has no executing of the sql command.. please read [ask], [tour] and most important [mcve]

Comment: updated hope that's more readable and reproducible

Comment: So, put in a break point and trace what happens.  Check this code is even running

Comment: You ** cannot** parametrize column (or table) names (`@selected`) in a T-SQL statement - you'll need to resort to **dynamic SQL** if you need to do this

Comment: thanks for that marc, good to know.

Comment: Will try using a switch based on column name.